# How to export Java JOGL GlueGen project in BlueJ?

Tags: java, jogl, bluej

I want to export my Java project to a standalone Jar or exe file. I use blueJ as an IDE and I use following libraries: GLOOP, JOGL and GlueGen (aswell as pi4j). Running the program in the IDE itself works flawlessly, however when I export the program as a .jar file and wrap it into an exe with Launch4j I get following error:

```
Catched IllegalArgumentException: No Jar name in <jar:file:/C:/Users/neche/Desktop/UfoSpiel.exe!/com/jogamp/common/os/Platform.class>, got <UfoSpiel.exe>, while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of null (null + null)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:454)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:59)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:90)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:328)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:390)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$2.run(Platform.java:249)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.loadGlueGenRTImpl(Platform.java:231)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:183)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:99)
    at GLOOP.GLRenderer.<init>(GLRenderer.java:90)
    at GLOOP.GLKamera.<init>(GLKamera.java:49)
    at UfoSzene.main(UfoSzene.java:14)
```

I use the Operating system Windows 64bit and BLuej version 414

I have googled a lot but never found someone who had the same problem or used the same OS or IDE.
It would be amazing if anyone of you could help.

Here is the main thread code:

```
import GLOOP.*;
public class UfoSzene
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GLKamera kamera;
        GLLicht licht; 
        GLBoden weltall;
        
        UfoSpiel ufoSpiel = new UfoSpiel();
        Punkte punkteStand = new Punkte();
        
        weltall = new GLBoden("Weltall.jpg");
        kamera = new GLKamera(800,800);
        kamera.setzePosition(2000,3001,20);
        kamera.setzeBlickpunkt(2000,0,0);
        licht = new GLLicht();
        
        
        ufoSpiel.start(); 
        punkteStand.start();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use System.load("path/to/binary") instead of System.loadLibrary() and instead of packing the binaries in your jar you can give absolute path in your OS as System.load() parameter. You can also prompt user to ask path of libraries at runtime before loading them if you dont want to statically link them

Comment: I am still new to this, what do you mean by binary?

Comment: what are you passing to the System.loadLibrary()

Comment: its better you show your code

Comment: How do I use System.load can someone please help there isn't much on the internet

Comment: Sinse you are using a wrapper there is no need of System.load() for you here but you need to add the path of the library in the java library path while executing the program something like java -Djava.library.path="path\to'library\bin" MainClass

Comment: I dont understand im 15 can you please write in baby language? Do I just copy paste the directory of the gluegen-rt.jar in the quotation marks?

Comment: Soo can you confirm what i just said?

Comment: Whats inside the directory which folders(is there something like bin(having files with .dll extension) )

Comment: so here is the solution inside your main(library) directory  there will be a folder called lib inside that there will be many folders open the one for your os then thats it this is the path. now while executing your jar add it there java -jar -Djava.library.path="path.to.the.dir" YourJar.jar it should work if there are no other problems

Comment: It didnt work. In launch4j I just added this <java -jar -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\neche\Downloads\Installation_GLOOP_3.7__Windows_\Installation GLOOP 3.7 (Windows)\lib\"gluegen-rt.jar> as commandline argument was that what you meant?

Comment: wrapping the java application is not that easy as you think here providing such a path will mean the app will work only on your computer instead you should pack the dlls with the application itself and in this kind of a thing i wouldnt recommend using Launch4J rather its a good idea to make a exe to launch the app your self as thats easier and

Comment: Rather ask JOGL specific questions on our official forum: https://forum.jogamp.org I don't know how to do that with BlueJ but I succeeded in doing something similar with my own tool based on Ant: https://tuer.sourceforge.io/en/documentation/#jndt I'm not sure that you can create a fat JAR with BlueJ.

Comment: By the way, you use an obsolete version of JOGL, please switch to JOGL 2.4 RC.